# Read data from text file, into numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to read the file of below format into numpy array in python.

```
ADIDGoogle#8a65c466-****-4a7e-****-0836c8884dae 2016-06-01  17:55:53
ADIDGoogle#8a65c466-****-4a7e-****-0836c8884dae 2016-06-01  17:55:53
ADIDGoogle#8a65c466-****-4a7e-****-0836c8884dae 2016-06-01  17:55:53
ADIDGoogle#8a664a70-****-4103-****-4f7e6cb9a33a 2016-06-01  13:20:02
ADIDGoogle#8a664a70-****-4103-****-4f7e6cb9a33a 2016-06-01  13:35:48
ADIDGoogle#8a664a70-****-4103-****-4f7e6cb9a33a 2016-06-01  13:26:20
ADIDGoogle#8a664a70-****-4103-****-4f7e6cb9a33a 2016-06-01  13:31:12
ADIDGoogle#8a664a70-****-4103-****-4f7e6cb9a33a 2016-06-01  13:19:17
ADIDGoogle#8a664a70-****-4103-****-4f7e6cb9a33a 2016-06-01  13:20:02
ADIDGoogle#8a664a70-****-4103-****-4f7e6cb9a33a 2016-06-01  13:36:39
ADIDGoogle#8a664a70-****-4103-****-4f7e6cb9a33a 2016-06-01  13:31:12
ADIDGoogle#8a664a70-****-4103-****-4f7e6cb9a33a 2016-06-01  13:35:48
```

it is having three columns separated by '\t'.
i want to read this into numpy array with two columns where the date and time in to one column and id in another column.

I tried using

```
Data = np.loadtxt(filename,dtype='string',usecols=(1,2),delimiter="\t")
```

but it is giving me error as :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `#` character in your file will make `numpy` think everything after "ADIDGoogle" in each line is a comment. It appears you can change the comment character using the `comments` kwarg in `np.loadtxt`. This will solve the `IndexError`, leaving the delimiter problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can read via `genfromtxt` line-by-line

```
import numpy as np

fname = "./data.txt"

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    data = np.genfromtxt(f,comments="!",dtype="string",usecols=(1,2))

print data
```